# Formview inside AccordionPane

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a formview inside an accordionpane control. How can I retrieve the text value from a textbox within formview1? Thanks!

```
--? TextBox start_date = (TextBox)FormView1.Row.FindControl("start_date");
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the FindCOntrol method on Databound event or ItemCreated Because I think that the formview have to be in editable mode to get the controls you could know it with something like this:

```
If FormView1.CurrentMode = FormViewMode.Edit Then
     'findControl()
End IF
```